# Leaflet filter data on zoom event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i have lots of data on leaflet map and i want to filter my layer data on zoom event . but i cant event access my layers as follows:

```
 this.map = L.map(this.target , {maxZoom:18 , minZoom:5 , zoomControl:false });   
 this.map.setView([23.8859, 45.0792], 5);          
 L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(this.map);
 // ...
  this.map.on("zoomend", function () { console.log(  this.layers["layer1"] );}); // problem
```

i got and error message like : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'layer1' of undefined`

what is the way to filter my data on events?

Answer (score 0):

You can access by defining the layer variable before adding it to map.

```js
      this.map = L.map(this.target, {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 5,
        zoomControl: false,
      });
      this.map.setView([23.8859, 45.0792], 5);
      var layer1 = L.tileLayer(
        "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      );
      layer1.addTo(this.map);
      this.map.on("zoomend", function () {
        console.log(layer1);
      });
```